# The Hadoop Hierarchy Puzzle

Tags: sql, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-pig

I have recently started working on Hadoop , my past experience is on ETL.
Now i have an issue where i want to build parent - child hierarchies. 
Below is the input-
**INPUT**

```
Parent_Id Child_Id

FAC001    FAC001

FAC001    FAC002

FAC002    FAC003

FAC003    FAC004

FAC004    FAC005

AAA005    AAA005 

AAA005    AAA001 

AAA001    AAA006
```

**Desired Output**

```
Top_Parent_Id Parent_Id Child_Id Level

FAC001        FAC001    FAC001   1

FAC001        FAC001    FAC002   2

FAC001        FAC002    FAC003   3

FAC001        FAC003    FAC004   4

FAC001        FAC004    FAC005   5

AAA005        AAA005    AAA005   1

AAA005        AAA005    AAA006   2
```

Can you please suggest a way to achieve this , I have implemented the same logic in hive where i was able to create the hierarchies to a pre- defined levels (Using Self Joins ).
But i was wondering if the same can be implemented in Spark or Pig upto n number of dynamic levels.

**Note** : Its not necessary that parent will be less than Child numerically or even alphabetically,Hence ordering should be avoided.
Appreciate all inputs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried [Spark SQL](http://spark.apache.org/sql/)?, hopefully you can translate the same logic you have in hive and then we can start from there

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a question about queries on graphs. You are given a graph (a hierarchical tree, or series of trees, in your first table, gives the directed edges of a tree) and you want all paths of a certain depth. This query is quite easy to express in graph frames, a third party package in spark 1.6. I would Google examples of it (can't do now, I'm on a train). But essentially, any query that is a repeated self join, is a query in a graph.

**EDIT**: I'm back home and this is a code sample that works with your data and finds depth 4 vertices starting from the top of the hierarchy (however, you have to define a motif and a query for each depth/level separately):

```
import org.graphframes._

// define a DataFrame of vertices - one of the columns must be "id"
val vertices = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
  ("FAC001", 1),
  ("FAC002", 1),
  ("FAC003", 1),
  ("FAC004", 1),
  ("FAC005", 1),
  ("AAA001", 1),
  ("AAA005", 1),
  ("AAA006", 1)
)).toDF("id", "some_attribute")

// define a DataFrame of edges - two columns must be "src" and "dst"
val edges = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
("FAC001", "FAC002"),
("FAC002", "FAC003"),
("FAC003", "FAC004"),
("FAC004", "FAC005"),
("AAA005", "AAA001"),
("AAA001", "AAA006")
)).toDF("src", "dst")

// define a GraphFrame
val hg = GraphFrame(vertices, edges)

// roots are those vertices which have no inDegree (only outDegrees)
val roots = vertices.select("id").except(hg.inDegrees.select("id"))

// define a path of length 4 
val motif = hg.find("(root1)-[]->(d1); (d1)-[]->(d2); (d2)-[]->(d3); (d3)-[]->(d4)")


// get only those paths of length 4 that start at the given root
val chain = motif.filter("root1.id = 'FAC001'").select($"root1.id".as("top_id"), $"d3.id".as("parent_id"), $"d4.id".as("child_id"))
```

Then try this in the shell:

```
scala> chain.show
+------+---------+--------+
|top_id|parent_id|child_id|
+------+---------+--------+
|FAC001|   FAC004|  FAC005|
+------+---------+--------+
```

[Graphframes](https://spark-packages.org/package/graphframes/graphframes) is a hybrid of SparkSQL and DataFrames - all you have to include is the package

```
--packages graphframes:graphframes:0.1.0-spark1.6
```

Comment: Thanks Kris , Appreciate the help .."Graph frames " ,never heard of it would do some research now , Although let me know if you have any other inputs whenever you are free.  Thanks again :)

Comment: Thanks @KrisP that was huge for me :) , Although i need to convince people at work to get this included in the package , I work for a bank and hence it is difficult to get anything implemented which is out of the package. But I will try this in the sandbox that i have created for my R&D and will get back to you , Thanks again , You are Awesome :)